# Finding eigenvalues of Sym$^k(\varphi)$, with $\varphi$ an operator from an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ to itself

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-polynomials

today I'm interested in solving a linear algebra problem concerning the symetric application.

Problem is: I work on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ with an operator $\varphi : V \to V$ having a completely decomposable characteristic polynomial. Considering $\{\mu_i\}$ to be the eigenvalues of $\varphi$, I would like to show that the eigenvalues of Sym$^k(\varphi)$ are given by $\{\mu_{i_1}...\mu_{i_k}\}$, for $1 \leq i_1 \leq \cdots \leq i_k \leq n$.

From there I have two questions concerning the data, first: is Sym the application: $\underbrace{V \otimes \cdots \otimes V}_{n \text{ times}} \to \underbrace{V \otimes \cdots \otimes V}_{n \text{ times}}$ such that Sym$(v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n) = \frac{1}{n!}\sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_n}v_{\sigma(1)} \cdots v_{\sigma(n)}$? Else what is it?

Second: I assume that a completely decomposable characteristic polynomial is such that it has $n$ (since dim($V) = n$) eigenvalues, all of algebraic multiplicity 1, but is that right? Because I never saw this expression before and I didn't find its equivalent in a book or on mathstack.

As you can guess, I can't move on the real question without this info, so any clue about this is welcome!

Have a nice day

Comment: Do you mean that the eigenvalues of $Sym^k(\varphi)$ are the $k$-fold **products** of the eigenvalues of $\varphi$? [Surely???]

Comment: Of course, I juste edited that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $\varphi:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear map, it induces a linear map $\varphi^{\otimes k}:V^{\otimes k}\rightarrow V^{\otimes k}$ by setting $$
\varphi(v_1 \otimes v_2\otimes \dots\otimes v_k)=\varphi(v_1)\otimes\dots\otimes\varphi(v_k)
$$ on rank 1 tensors and extending linearly. Consider the subspace $S^k(V)$ of symmetric $k$-tensors. You may show that $\varphi^{\otimes k}(S^k(V))\subset S^k(V)$, i.e., $\varphi^{\otimes k}$ maps $S^k(V)$ to itself. This map is what you denote by $Sym^k(\varphi)=\varphi^{\otimes k}_{\mid S^k(V)}$.

Now say $\varphi$ is a diagonalizible matrix with eigenvalues $\mu_1,\mu_2,\dots,\mu_n$ and eigenvectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$. Now, set $$
v_{i_1}v_{i_2}\dots v_{i_k}=\sum_{\sigma\in S_k} v_{i_{\sigma(1)}}\otimes v_{i_{\sigma(2)}}\otimes\dots\otimes v_{i_{\sigma(k)}}
$$ be the symmetric product. All symmetric products of this form gives us a basis for $S^k(V)$. Observe that $$
\begin{split}
Sym^k(\varphi)(v_{i_1}v_{i_2}\dots v_{i_k}) &= Sym^k(\varphi)\big(\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}v_{i_{\sigma(1)}}\otimes\dots\otimes v_{i_{\sigma(k)}}\big)\\
&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\varphi(v_{i_{\sigma(1)}})\otimes\dots\otimes \varphi(v_{i_{\sigma(k)}})\\
&=\mu_{i_1}\mu_{i_2}\dots\mu_{i_k}\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}v_{i_{\sigma(1)}}\otimes\dots\otimes v_{i_{\sigma(k)}}\\
&=(\mu_{i_1}\mu_{i_2}\dots\mu_{i_k}) v_{i_1}v_{i_2}\dots v_{i_k}.
\end{split}
$$ This shows the result for diagonalizible $\varphi$. However, the set of diagonalizible matrices is dense in $End(V)$, so the result also holds for all $\varphi$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! Would you care to explain the part when you say "It is easy to see that.." because it's not obvious in my mind

Comment: Let me add that.

Comment: Ah okey I see, thank you!

Comment: Looking back on this problem this morning, I'm wondering if the same result would hold for the eigenvalues of $\bigwedge^k(\varphi)$ ?

Comment: @Rhaena yes, you can apply the same argument. The eigenvalues of $S^k(V)$ are all monomials in $\dim(V)$ variables and degree $k$, each appear with multiplicity $1$. The eigenvalues of $\Lambda^k(V)$ are all multilinear monomials of degree $k$, i.e. monomials such that every variable has degree at most $1$. That's because for an expression $v_1\wedge v_2\wedge \dots\wedge v_k\neq 0$, we necessarily have $v_i\neq v_j$ for $i\neq j$.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for explaining my intuition haha ! it makes sens!

Comment: I'm sorry after read your explanation I think it's not clear for me, I have a question like that. I'm wondering if we can reasoning with a matrix of Jordan of $\phi$ since we know that eigenvalues are all distinct ?  What do you think @Levent

Comment: Otherwise, can you explain just why you did it, and why it show the assumption ?